# HTML Counter that starts at 15 minutes and goes until button press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdowntimer

I'm trying to make a little HTML page with 2 buttons on it and 1 drop down (Eventually I will multiply this by 5).

The first button activates a small timer that starts at 15 minutes and goes into the negatives until the button is pressed again.

The second button does the exact same thing, but starts at 30 minutes and goes down into the negatives until the button is pressed again.

The drop down just has a list of all employees.

I have found many different timers, but none of them go into the negatives. and if I remove the if statement that checks for negatives, it just doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this negative counter?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var secs = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        secs++; console.log(secs);
        if (secs > 5) {
            clearInterval(id);
            alert('Total Time: ' + secs + ' seconds');
        }
    }, 1000);
});

######Javascript:

window.onload = function () {
    var secs = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        secs++; console.log(secs);
        if (secs > 5) {
            clearInterval(id);
            alert('Total Time: ' + secs + ' seconds');
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```js
(function (javascript) {
    // An Array with the doms and their cancellation functions
    var buttonList = [];

    /**
     * Toggles each button's timer
     * @param {HTMLElement} dom 
     * @param {number} timer 
     * @returns {void}
     */
    function toggleButton(dom, timer) {
        // find the object for the dom in the list
        var result = buttonList.find(function (item) {
            return item.dom === dom;
        });
        // if it is found 
        if (result) {
            // stop the timer
            result.cancel();
            // reset the text to default
            print(timerFormat(timer));
            // remove the object from the list
            var index = buttonList.indexOf(result);
            buttonList.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            // if it isn't found then start the timer and add the object to the list
            buttonList.push({
                cancel: startTimer(timer, print),
                dom: dom
            });
        }
        /**
         * Changes the text of the element
         * @param {string} text 
         * @returns {void}
         */
        function print(text) {
            dom.innerText = text;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a timer and returns a cancelation function
     * @param {number} timer 
     * @param {function(string): void} print
     * @returns {function(): void}
     */
    function startTimer(timer, print) {
        var intervalId = setInterval(onTick, 1000);
        return cancel;
        function onTick() {
            var result = timerFormat(timer--);
            if (typeof print === "function") print(result);
            else console.log(result);
        }
        function cancel() {
            if (intervalId) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                intervalId = undefined;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts the seconds into [mm:ss] format
     * @param {number} timer
     * @returns {string}
     */
    function timerFormat(timer) {
        var negative = false;
        if (timer < 0) {
            timer = timer * -1;
            negative = true;
        }
        var minutes = Math.floor(timer / 60);
        var seconds = String(timer % 60);
        var symbol = negative ? "- " : "";
        return symbol + minutes + ":" + "0".repeat(2 - seconds.length) + seconds;
    }

    javascript.toggleButton = toggleButton;
})(window);
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleButton(this, 900)">15:00</button>
<button onclick="toggleButton(this, 1800)">30:00</button>
```

Comment: So maybe im just really dumb, but i ran your snippit, looked perfect. Then i tried copying and pasting (top main section into a <Script></script> tag and the small part into the body html. and the buttons show up but the timer box does not... what did i do wrong?

Comment: @BenjaminBusath That's because I was using the `console.log` function which prints in the browser's console which is not visible to the user. To view it pres `ctrl + shift + i`. I've changed my answer to show the time on the buttons to help you. If there is anything you don't understand about the code, please let me know.

Comment: @ nick zoum This is Fantastic! The only thing is now to get it to go into the negatives...

Comment: @BenjaminBusath Does it have a problem?

Comment: Yeah, when it goes to negatives it shows 0:00 then the next number jumps to -1:-1, -1:-2 then all the way to -1:-9 then it stops.

Comment: @BenjaminBusath It seems to be working fine on the snippet. Can you copy the code again to make sure you haven't missed anything. Cause I had made several edits to the answer, so it's possible you didn't get the latest version.

Comment: you were right! I re copied it and its perfect now! Thanks again!!

Comment: @BenjaminBusath Great, please let me know if there is anything you don't understand about the code, so I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var myTimer;
var started = false
var count = 15 * 60; //15 mins x 60 secs

$("button").click(function() {
  if (!started) {
    started = true;
    $(this).text("Stop");
    myTimer = setInterval(function() {
      $(".timer").text(--count);
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    started = false;
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    $(this).text("Start");
  }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4vqz4w34/)

Please note that I implemented only the 15 mins timer. You can replicate the code for the 30 mins one.

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but why create a fiddle when you can create a snippet?

Comment: @nickzoum Less messy and easier to share :)